# Data Binding Issue text in label is not displaying data

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm

The following **Label** does not show data while running it `<Label Text="{Binding Firstname}"`/> if I run code in Debug mode and if I change **Label** to *Editor* or something else it shows data.
Please let me know why is that and how can I solve it.

**Code Behind**
*Private fields*

```
    private string email;
    private string phone;
    private string firstname;
    private string lastname;
```

*Method calling data from **FirebaseFirestore***

```
        public async Task GetDataAsync()
    {
       var user = await DependencyService.Get<IAccountService>().GetUserAsync();

        phone = user.Phone;
        email = user.Email;
        firstname = user.Firstname;
        lastname = user.Lastname;
    }
```

*Public properties*

```
     public string Firstname
    {
        get { return firstname; }
        set
        {
            firstname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Firstname));
        }
    }
    public string Lastname
    {
        get {return lastname;}
        set
        {
            lastname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Lastname));

        }
    }

    public string Email
    {
        set
        {
            if (email != value)
            {
                email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Email");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return email;
        }
    }
    public string Phone
    {
        set
        {
            if (phone != value)
            {
                phone = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Phone");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return phone;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you do the binding? And how do you use this label? In listView? If yes, have you reset the ItemsSource?

Comment: Thanks for the reply its a separate label only as you can see I am putting value on the backend property of the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
firstname = user.Firstname;
```

Must be changed to:

```
Firstname = user.Firstname;
```

Explanation:

If you don't use the Firstname property setter, then `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Firstname));` never gets called.

So XAML does not know that the property's value has changed.

Comment: Thanks Steve it solved my issue.